# Can I as a normal user run stuff under a managed service account?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-service, managed-service-accounts

Let's say I have remote access to a server which uses MSA's to run application pools and windows services. Can I as a normal (not elevated) user run program's under those MSA's?

For example

```
PsExec.exe -u domain\MsaAccount$ cmd.exe
```

I would say no, but I need to make sure. It's not that I don't know that they can be used to run stuff like services. I just don't want users without elevated rights to use them to do stuff they aren't allowed to.

Comment: MSA or gMSA? Because MSA's don't exist in a domain, only gMSA's do.

Comment: @Daniel the question is about both.

Comment: Oh, okay, I was confused about the "domain" part.

Comment: You can certainly run scripts as a MSA. This might help you find a way doing it with programs, too: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/

Comment: @Daniel MSA's are stored in AD under CN=Managed Service Accounts, DC=<domain>, DC=<com>. It's not that I don't know that they can be used to run stuff like services. I just don't want users without elevated rights to use them to do stuff they aren't allowed to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command with a Managed Service Account?](https://serverfault.com/questions/736651/run-command-with-a-managed-service-account)

Comment: Hi, I flagged as a duplicate because the answer is a good's one for you, as yes it can be run, and no need for the account password to run it..

Comment: The answer of the other question doesn't state if it's possible to run it as a non elevated account.